# In iOS 13, when to save data?

Tags: ios, save, ios13

Scene support and multiple windows in iOS 13 have complicated the question of when to save data. A scene delegate's `sceneDidEnterBackground` might seem like a pretty good place, but there are times when it won't be sufficient:

- If your scene was frontmost and the user goes to the app switcher and terminates your app, you'll get `sceneDidDisconnect` and `applicationWillTerminate`, not `sceneDidEnterBackground`.
- If the user switches off the device while your app is frontmost, you'll get `applicationWillTerminate`, not `sceneDidEnterBackground`.

What strategy are people using to manage data saving in iOS 13 apps that support window scenes and possibly multiple windows?

Comment: Here's a 3rd case: The user has multiple scenes of your app open (each full screen). While viewing one of those full screen scenes in the foreground, if they then switch to the app switcher and swipe that most recent scene off the top of the screen, that scene does have its `sceneDidEnterBackground` called. The app is not terminated because there is still another scene (currently in the background).

Comment: I meant "does", I did not mean "does not". Run your app. Get it so two scenes are showing on screen side by side. Slide the divider to the edge of the screen leaving one scene full screen. Of course the other goes to the background and `sceneDidEnterBackground` is called for that one. Now double-tap the home button to bring up the app switcher. You see the two scenes. If you swipe the scene that you just left in the foreground, that killed scene will now have its `sceneDidEnterBackground` called. At least that's the case for my app.

Comment: @rmaddy Well, I'm finding this extraordinarily confusing, not least because I get different results in the simulator and on a device, and also because console caveman debugging with OSLog is not entirely dependable. The case where the user swipes us up in the app switcher is so difficult that I've created a separate Q-and-A for it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58573015/in-ios-13-what-events-do-i-get-when-the-user-swipes-my-app-up-in-the-app-switch

Comment: If I read your answer to that other question correctly (which matches what I'm seeing and what I posted here in my earlier comments), then doesn't that make your first bullet point in this question incorrect? You in fact do get a call to `sceneDidEnterBackground` in that scenario (and `applicationWillTerminate`).

Comment: @rmaddy Well that turns out to be the odd-man-out scenario that I focus on in my other answer: an app that has scene support but with multiple windows turned off, running on an iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs for [`UISceneDelegate.sceneWillResignActive(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3197919-scenewillresignactive):

> If your scene has unsaved user data, save that data here to ensure that it isn't lost. However, never save data solely from this method. Instead, save it at appropriate points from your view controllers, usually in response to user actions. For example, save data when the user dismisses a data-entry screen. *Do not rely on specific app transitions to save all of your app's critical data*.

They also state in the docs for [`UISceneDelegate.sceneDidDisconnect(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3197916-scenediddisconnect):

> Use this method to perform any final cleanup before your scene is purged from memory. For example, use it to release references to files or shared resources and *to save user data*.

So it looks like Apple recommends that we save user data as events happen, like in response to the user doing something (dismissing a view controller, toggling a switch, entering text into a text field, etc.), but we may use `sceneWillResignActive(_:)` and/or `sceneDidDisconnect(_:)` to save some data if we need or want to.

Comment: Yes, I thought of willResignActive. My worry is that comes so frequently. Opening the notification center you get it twice. Still, it’s interesting that this confirms what I was starting to conclude on my own.

Comment: I have found 9 cases when `willResignActive` is called. It is so weird that it is called 2 times when opening notification center, as @matt said. This is still the case on iOS 16.