# In iOS 13, what events do I get when the user swipes my app up in the app switcher?

Tags: ios, kill, ios13

I'm finding it extraordinarily difficult to categorize and account for what events I get (or don't get) when the user swipes my app up in the app switcher on iOS 13. This seems to be because of changes caused by the multiple scene support. What are the events that I get in that situation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's assume that your app supports window scenes. So what the user is swiping up in the app switcher is really a *scene*, not your app as a whole. Then the possibilities appear to be as follows.

#### On an iPhone

If the scene was frontmost:

- `sceneDidEnterBackground`
- `applicationWillTerminate(_:)`

But if the scene was not frontmost, you'll get nothing; you already received `sceneDidEnterBackground`, and you won't get `applicationWillTerminate(_:)` now because the app isn't running.

#### On an iPad, if the app does *not* support multiple windows

If the scene was frontmost:

- `sceneDidDisconnect(_:)`
- `application(_:didDiscardSceneSessions:)`
- `applicationWillTerminate(_:)`

But if the scene was not frontmost, you'll get nothing; you already received `sceneDidEnterBackground`, and you won't get `applicationWillTerminate(_:)` now because the app isn't running.

#### On an iPad, if the app *does* support multiple windows

If the scene was frontmost:

- `sceneDidEnterBackground`
- `applicationWillTerminate(_:)` (perhaps)

But if the scene was not frontmost, you'll get nothing; you already received `sceneDidEnterBackground`, and you won't get `applicationWillTerminate(_:)` now because either the app isn't running or the app isn't terminating (if there's another window). If the app is still running, you might get `sceneDidDisconnect(_:)` and possibly `application(_:didDiscardSceneSessions:)` later.

---

### Conclusions

What's the odd-man-out here? It's the case where we're running on an iPad and we support scenes but *not* multiple windows. We don't get `sceneDidEnterBackground`! I regard that as incoherent. Since we don't support multiple windows, this is basically an iPhone app and it should behave like an iPhone app. I shouldn't have to double up my code just because my app runs on both iPhone and iPad.

Comment: Can you eliminate the "odd-man-out" scenario? Don't take steps to opt-out of supporting multiple windows. Just don't provide the user any way to create a second scene. At moment, I can't remember if there is some iPad way for a user to create multiple scenes even if your app doesn't provide some obvious way for the user to create a new scene.

Comment: @rmaddy I’m not taking any steps. This is with the app you get right from the templates.

Comment: I never get the applicationWillTerminate anymore, what did I do wrong?

Comment: What do you do if you want to do something different when the scene is disconnected than you do when the scene goes to background? Working as explained, there's no purpose for `sceneDidDisconnect`. It isn't reliably called when the last scene is dismissed. What is the reason for not calling `applicationWillTerminate` when the application goes from background state to terminated state?

Comment: I tried on iPhone with disabling multiple windows and got both called  `sceneDidDisconnect(_:)` & `application(_:didDiscardSceneSessions:)`.
I think iPhone not differ from the iPad, the only thing that determine the lifecycle or which one will get called is by **enabling or disabling multiple windows**

Answer (score -1):

in my case, I want to save user state when the app is terminated by the user or the system, `applicationWillTerminate(_:)` does not being called for me most of the time.

I achieved what I want by using `sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene)`

Comment: That is true but (a) it is well known and (b) it is not what the question was about. I asked what events I _do_ get, not when to save state. I know when to save state.