# sceneDidDisconnect(_:) not called when user close the window in switcher

Tags: ios, ios13, ipados

I add `sceneDidDisconnect(_:)` delegate method to `SceneDelegate` in apple's **Supporting Multiple Windows on iPad** sample code (can be downloaded in Xcode documentation window). But when I ran the app and open multiple windows, this method won't be called when any of the windows was closed. Should I do something else?

Comment: Did you figure it out. Also having the problem that sceneDidDisconnect does not get called.

Comment: Here's a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58573015/in-ios-13-what-events-do-i-get-when-the-user-swipes-my-app-up-in-the-app-switch/58573016#58573016