# Why isn't didDiscardSceneSessions called?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have an iOS 13 only app. I need to perform some work in `didDiscardSceneSessions`. My understanding is that you "discard" a scene by entering app expose and swiping up on a scene to make it disappear.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions:
    Set<UISceneSession>) {
    print("❗️didDiscardSceneSessions")
}
```

When I add a breakpoint or a print command to this function, it's never called. Above is an example.

According to to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/3197906-application?language=objc)...

> When the user removes a scene from the app switcher, UIKit calls this method before discarding the scene's associated session object altogether. (UIKit also calls this method to discard scenes that it can no longer display.) If your app is not running, UIKit calls this method the next time your app launches.

I can't seem to trigger this method at all. I'm using a physical iPad as my test device.

---

## Updates

I did some more tinkering, and it turns out that `sceneDidDisconnect` isn't called either after closing a window.

---

I did some testing in a new, single view app. I put a breakpoint in `didDiscardSceneSessions` and it worked. Then I set "Enable Multiple Windows" in info.plist to "YES" and it stopped working. What gives?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58573015/in-ios-13-what-events-do-i-get-when-the-user-swipes-my-app-up-in-the-app-switch. See my answer there. Basically, you might get `didDiscard` later but that's up to the runtime. In a true multiple windows app, the system hangs on to the session as long as it can. So you have no way of knowing when it will in fact be discarded. I think the documentation is a little coy about this.

Comment: Okay. That answers my question. Pretty frustrating. Thank you, once again, matt! Your help is always appreciated.

Comment: Try hitting the "power" button to make the device lock. Does that force UIKit to flush any scenes and/or sessions?