# Best approach to use UserDefaults

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I just started to learn swift, decided to make the first todo app and I had a question. It is necessary to save all data during any user actions: creating, changing or deleting a task. Calling a method to save data each time is a bad approach. What can you recommend?

```
func addItem(itemName: String, isCompleted: Bool = false) {
   tasks.append(Tasks(taskName: itemName, isCompleted: isCompleted))
   saveData()
}
```

I store tasks in a structure. Before using the structure, I used computed property like this:

```
var ToDoItems: [[String: Any]] {
   set {
     UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "ToDoDataKey")
     UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
   }

   get {
     if let userData = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "ToDoDataKey") as? 
 [[String: Any]] {
       return userData
   } else {
     return []
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: User defaults isn't a great place to save data. It's fine for a quick and dirty solution while you get the rest of your app up and running, but it's not meant for saving large amounts of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **`didSet`** of `tasks` `array`, you can simply set the current array elements in `UserDefaults`.

```
struct Task: Codable {
    let taskName: String
    let isCompleted: Bool
}

var tasks = [Task]() {
    didSet {
        let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(tasks)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "ToDoDataKey")
    }
}

func addItem(itemName: String, isCompleted: Bool = false) {
    tasks.append(Task(taskName: itemName, isCompleted: isCompleted))
}
```

This will ensure that the data in `UserDefaults` is synchronized with that currently in the memory.

And fetch the data only in `viewDidLoad()` where the data will be loaded for the first time.

```
func fetchTasks() -> [Task] {
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "ToDoDataKey"), let tasks = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Task].self, from: data) {
        return tasks
    }
    return []
}
```

Call `fetchTasks()` in `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: Saving your json data inside a property list doesn't make any sense. Why don't you simply save the JSON data straight to disk inside the application support directory ?

Comment: Note that the data size will increase considerably, It will unnecessarily be base64 encoded when stored inside UserDefaults.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to hit the disk every time the task array changes. The usual thing is to register for the UIApplication [notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622973-willresignactivenotification) that tells you that your app is about to deactivate, and save to defaults there.

You only need to retrieve from defaults on `viewDidLoad`, as you've already been told.

(In iOS 13 with multiple window support, things are a little more complicated; see [In iOS 13, when to save data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58567287/in-ios-13-when-to-save-data).)